# Spresenseとアナログマイク4CHを使用した録音が失敗する

Tags: spresense

Spresenseとアナログマイク4CHを用いて、音声を30秒ごとに録音するプログラムを作成しました。
プログラムのベースは以下の「Spresense Arduino チュートリアル」にある「WAV 形式で録音する」で、これを30秒録音するごとにファイル名を変えることで、延々と録音するように変更したものです。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html

これを実行したところ、まれ（1時間に1回程度)に録音が以下のメッセージをして失敗する現象が発生します。

```
Attention: module[4][0] attention id[1]/code[6] (objects/media_recorder/audio_recorder_sink.cpp L84)
```

この原因と対処方法について考えられることがあれば、アドバイスいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: SD カードの書き込み速度が録音データ量に追い付いていない可能性がありそうっス。音声品質を落としてデータ量を減らすといけるかも（的外れかも）

Comment: デジタルマイクの記事ですが同じ場所で同じエラーらしいです。[Digital Microphones and Arduino](https://forum.developer.sony.com/topic/71/digital-microphones-and-arduino)

Answer (score 1):

SDカードはメーカ、使用状況などで書き込み速度が極端に遅くなる時があるようです。
自分の時も、特に、細かいファイルを書き込み、削除などを繰り返していると、
中途半端に書き込まれたセクタなどが多く存在してかなり書き込みが遅くなっていました。

書き込みが遅くなったSDカードを使うとこのエラーが出るようです。

このようなときは、クイックフォーマットでは改善されず、SD Associationにある、
SDメモリカードフォーマッターで物理フォーマットすると改善されました。

https://www.sdcard.org/jp/downloads/formatter/

また、メーカにもかなり依存するようです。
東芝製かソニー製だとエラーの確率が低く、
Amazonで売っている安いSanDisk(偽物？)は全然ダメでした。

ご参考になれば。